# How can I compile Opencv API on gcc

Tags: opencv, gcc, header, linker

I am trying to compile an an .C file which contains API from Opencv library.
It seems the compiler doesn't find the API. I use the normal command for compilation

```
   gcc new.c -c
   gcc new.o -o new1 -l highgui
```

highgui is a .h file which is calling other .h files from Opencv lib

I think I have the same problem as the thread below as I get almost same error.

[GCC: How can I make this compiling and linking work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889048/gcc-how-can-i-make-this-compiling-and-linking-work)

Answer (score 6):

You can use **pkg-config** command to get the compiler/linker options. Like this

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags opencv` `pkg-config --libs opencv` new.c
```

Please note the above punctuation is ` not '.

Or you can use **CMake**. Write a *CMakeLists.txt* like this

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (new1)
find_package (OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories (${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable (new1 new.c)
target_link_libraries (new1 ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

then you can build like this

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DOpenCV_DIR=<the-directory-contating-OpenCVConfig.cmake> ..
make
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below command

```
gcc -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include/opencv2 -L/usr/local/lib/ -g -o binary  main.c -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui
```

Assumes OpenCV installed on /usr/local directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try the command [Harris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20370076/661211) wrote. 
It tells Your compiler to look for header files additionally in `/usr/local/include/opencv` and `/usr/local/include/opencv2` directories (`-I` switch), and look for libraries in `/usr/local/lib/` (`-L`). Next it tells the linker with `-l` switch to link libraries opencv_core and etc...

When You will encounter this type of problem, You need to find library files, tell compiler the path to them and tell him which libraries to link, OMITTING THE LIB PART IN NAME, for example `opencv_core` instead of `libopencv_core`.