# How to compile C++ code that contains OpenCV library without Makefile?

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile

I just started learning OpenCV with C++. I built OpenCV from source on Linux machine. I use Visual Studio Code text editor. I want to compile C++ code that contains OpenCV library without Makefile. I added `/usr/local/opencv4/**` to `includePath` variable. But it didn't work. I'm receiving opencv2/opencv.hpp error. Is it possible build C++ code that contains OpenCV includes without Makefile? How can I do it?

My Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
  
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat image = imread("Enter the Address"
                       "of Input Image",
                       IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
  
    if (image.empty()) {
        cout << "Image File "
             << "Not Found" << endl;
  
        cin.get();
        return -1;
    }
  
    imshow("Window Name", image);
  
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you compile it in the Makefile? Just compile it the same way.

Comment: @yees_7 I don't want to use Makefile. I don't know anything about Makefiles

Comment: I looked at documentation for build from source

Comment: What about `CMake`?

Comment: Related: [How can I compile OpenCV API on gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366010/how-can-i-compile-opencv-api-on-gcc) - The answer under the question contains a solution using `pkg-config`.

Comment: With no build extensions for CMake or Makefiles you would edit your args: of your `tasks.json`

Comment: I used CMake while building OpenCV from source. There is CMake in official OpenCV documentation. But I don't know CMake

Comment: Probably follow the link from @kotatsuyaki it shows manual compilation and CMake

Comment: what is wrong in learning Make or CMake

Answer (score 1):

You will have to tell the compiler the location of the header files and library files. As mentioned by kotatsuyaki you can use pkg-config to do this for your.

Example with gcc and pkg-config:

```
g++ *.cpp -o program_name `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`
```

Example with gcc and without pkg-config:

```
g++ *.cpp -o program_name -I/PATH/TO/OPENCV/INCLUDE/FOLDER -L/PATH/TO/OPENCV/LIB/FOLDER -lopencv_something -lopencv_somethingelse ... etc
```

In Windows with cl you can do the same as the g++ without pkg-config:

```
cl main.cpp /I"PATH TO OPENCV ICNLUDE FOLDER" /link /LIBPATH:"PATH TO OPENCV LIB FOLDER" opencv_library1.lib opencv_libarary2.lib ... etc.
```